# port forward http port (80) on virgin super hub

Tags: http, port

I am currently working on a project to make my apache server live, which is new me so this is the first time I am doing anything like this. basically I have gone in to the router and  requested port forwarding on port 80 for my local IP address, but to no effect. when I test it with a web tool which tells you if a port is open or not it says it's closed. More confusingly when I run a netstsat -a command it shows http as listening. I'm not sure if its a firewall issue or I'm going about it all wrong. any Ideas would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to be testing from outside your local network.  If you run netstat on your server, of course it is going to say "listening".  Is your web testing tool being run from outside your firewall?  You should also be able to turn off wifi on your phone and test hitting your broadband IP address:80.  Are you forwarding from port 80 on your router to port 80 on your server?  Is it possible that your provider is blocking port 80 for residential accounts?

Answer (score 0):

First google for an online port scanner and ask it to scan port 80.
Second if you're using Ubuntu ufw (firewall) is probably running default deny rules so do this: sudo ufw allow 80

To check it's working just plug your WAN IP into your browser URL bar, it should connect to your test page in /var/www/html/index.html